# Scala pattern match json

Tags: json, scala, playframework, websocket

im trying to use the Anonymous chat app provided by the Activator for my own purpose .i need to fire a case depending on a json field value. i have a code like this.

```
 def receive = LoggingReceive {
 case js: JsValue => {
  (js \ "status").validate[String] map {
    Utility.escape(_)
  }map {
    board ! Message(uid, _)
  }
```

i want to match the status field with string values. i tried this approach

```
 (js \ "status").validate[String] map {
    Utility.escape(_)
  }toString match {
    case "play" =>
      board ! Message(uid, "play")
    case "stop" =>
      board ! Message(uid, "stop")
  }
```

but im getting an java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
im coming from java background and a total newbie to Scala
any help would be much appriciated

Comment: It as nothing to do with JSON and/or pattern matching.It's the connections (channels) that are broken (closed unexpectedly).

Comment: Sam, matching code looks ok, but the toString is not doing what you want. And it is probably affecting your pattern matching. Please remove the toString and add a case e => Logger.error(s" Received: e") and you will see the matching issue.

Comment: If you want to learn about pattern matching take a look at http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're matching against the result of `validate[String]`, which is either [`JsSuccess`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess) or [`JsError`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsError), so I would do something like this:

```
(js \ "status").validate[String] match {
  case JsSuccess("play", _) => board ! Message(uid, "play")
  case JsSuccess("stop", _) => board ! Message(uid, "stop")
  case _ => // something else!
}
```

If "play" and "stop" are the only values you expecting you could simplify that by binding the command in the extractor directly:

```
(js \ "status").validate[String] match {
  case JsSuccess(cmd, _) => board ! Message(uid, cmd)
}
```

If you really don't care about the value of status if it doesn't exist or is something else, using `asOpt` instead of `validate` might be easier:

```
(js \ "status").asOpt[String].map { cmd =>
  board ! Message(uid, cmd)
}
```